# How to find all text inside <p> elements in an HTML page using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, unicode, html-parsing, beautifulsoup

I need to find all the visible tags inside paragraph elements in an HTML file using BeautifulSoup in Python.
For example,
    `<p>Many hundreds of named mango <a href="/wiki/Cultivar" title="Cultivar">cultivars</a> exist.</p>`
should return:
    `Many hundreds of cultivars exist.`

P.S. Some files contain Unicode characters (Hindi) which need to be extracted.
Any ideas how to do that?

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/517923/what-is-the-best-way-to-remove-accents-in-a-python-unicode-string for removing unicode in Python.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's how you can do it with BeautifulSoup. This will remove any tags not in VALID_TAGS but keep the content of the removed tags.

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup

VALID_TAGS = ['div', 'p']

soup = BeautifulSoup(value)

for tag in soup.findAll('p'):
    if tag.name not in VALID_TAGS:
        tag.replaceWith(tag.renderContents())

print soup.renderContents()
```

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1765848/remove-a-tag-using-beautifulsoup-but-keep-its-contents)

Answer (score 14):

```
soup.findAll('p')
```

here is a [reference](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs3/documentation.html#The%20basic%20find%20method%3a%20findAll%28name,%20attrs,%20recursive,%20text,%20limit,%20%2a%2akwargs%29)