# Deleting anything but plain Text in python

Tags: python, urllib

I am trying to make the code only get every thing in between the `<p>` tags. I haven't found a way yet.

I've tried to use a simple loop, and this porgramme you are suppose to enter an url and when you run it shows the plain text.

```
    import urllib.request
    import urllib.parse
    import re

    print("Enter the URL")
    url = input()

    #url = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Somalia"
    values = {'s':'basic', 'submit':'search'}
    data = urllib.parse.urlencode(values)
    data = data.encode('utf-8')
    req = urllib.request.Request(url,data)
    resp = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
    respData = resp.read()

    #print(respData)

    paragraphs = re.findall(r'<p>(.*?)</p>', str(respData))

    for eachP in paragraphs:
        print(eachP)
```

I have also tried to use BeutifulSoup and haven't even managed to import it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to find all text inside <p> elements in an HTML page using BeautifulSoup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10113702/how-to-find-all-text-inside-p-elements-in-an-html-page-using-beautifulsoup)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: Regular expressions  are NOT the way to parse XML, even if they would work for simple ones. It is strongly advised to use an XML parser.

Comment: I there any simpler way besides XML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to SO and programming. [You can't parse [X]HTML with regex.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags?noredirect=1&lq=1) Time to use libraries. [Beautiful Soup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) and is your [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/install/#pipenv-install-requests) are your best friends here.

in your bash/cmd/terminal type:

```
pip install requests
pip install beautifulsoup4
```

Then use:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


r = requests.get("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Somalia")
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text) # you need to define the parser but for now its ok.
for p in soup.find_all('p'):
    print(p.text)
```