# How to get text within the `p` tag using Beautiful Soup?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I wanna get all the p tags and store it in a list, but unfortunately all of them have a 
 between.

This is how the content looks like:

```
<p>Ich halt mir die Pistole an den Kopf
 <br/>Doch drück' nicht ab, denn ich hab zu viel Angst vor Gott</p>,
 <p>Feinde wurden zu Brüdern
 <br/>Und Brüder wurden zu V-Männern
 <br/>Die beste Gang, in der ich jemals war
 <br/>Me, myself und meine DNA</p>,
```

and i should look like:

```
[Ich halt mir die Pistole an den Kopf
    Doch drück' nicht ab, denn ich hab zu viel Angst vor Gott, Feinde wurden zu Brüdern
     Und Brüder wurden zu V-Männern
     Die beste Gang, in der ich jemals war
     Me, myself und meine DNA,]
```

Thats my current code:

```
url = requests.get("https://www.myzitate.de/suche/farid-bang/")
z = bs(url.content)
cont = z.find("div", attrs={"id":"cont"})
cont.find_all("p")
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to find all text inside <p> elements in an HTML page using BeautifulSoup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10113702/how-to-find-all-text-inside-p-elements-in-an-html-page-using-beautifulsoup)

Comment: xKuramaa, as webmaster of myzitate.de I'd find it interesting why you're trying to scrape content from my page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

```py
ps = [p.get_text() for p in cont.find_all("p")]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `tag.get_text()` with parameters `strip=True` and `separator='\n'` to get correct text:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = 'https://www.myzitate.de/suche/farid-bang/'
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, 'html.parser')

for p in soup.select('p'):
    print(p.get_text(strip=True, separator='\n'))
    print('-' * 80)
```

Prints:

```
Ich halt mir die Pistole an den Kopf
Doch drück' nicht ab, denn ich hab zu viel Angst vor Gott
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Feinde wurden zu Brüdern
Und Brüder wurden zu V-Männern
Die beste Gang, in der ich jemals war
Me, myself und meine DNA
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Wir sind Public Enemy
Ihr Police Academy
Kann nicht tanzen, meine Schultern sind zu breit
Du willst mich batteln und frisst dann den Bürgersteig
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Wir kam'n von unten mit Gangsta-Rap
Und sind im Endeffekt drei Gs wie das Handynetz
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

...and so on.
```

Answer (score 0):

All the items are located under the `id` of `z` which is accessible via

```
page_soup.find_all('div', {'id': 'z'}):
```

In some website, the are multiple instances where the p tag exist, so I usually will search for upper class just to make sure I get the intended output.

The text you interested are within the `p tag` and retrievable via

```
div_tag.find_all('p')
```

The full code is as below:

```
append_text=[]
url = requests.get("https://www.myzitate.de/suche/farid-bang/")
page_soup= Soup(url.content)
for div_tag in page_soup.find_all('div', {'id': 'z'}):
    for litag in div_tag.find_all('p'):
        append_text.append(litag.text)
```