# How do I use BeautifulSoup to replace a tag with its contents?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

How would I use BeautifulSoup to remove *only* a tag? The method I found deletes the tag and *all* other tags and content inside it. I want to remove only the tag and leave everything inside it untouched, e.g.

change this:

```
<div>
<p>dvgbkfbnfd</p>
<div>
<span>dsvdfvd</span>
</div>
<p>fvjdfnvjundf</p>
</div>
```

to this:

```
<p>dvgbkfbnfd</p>
<span>dsvdfvd</span>
<p>fvjdfnvjundf</p>
```

Comment: Conceptually, you want to [replace](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs3/documentation.html#Replacing%20one%20Element%20with%20Another) the `<div>` with its contents.

Comment: +1 to that.  The tag includes its contents -- it doesn't make any conceptual sense from the perspective of the parser to delete the tag without deleting the contents (it would be like deleting a directory but not deleting any files inside it).  So you need to replace the tag itself with its own contents.

Comment: perfect :) this worked, i never thought about it that way.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Remove a tag using BeautifulSoup but keep its contents](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1765848/remove-a-tag-using-beautifulsoup-but-keep-its-contents)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've voted to close as a duplicate, but in case it's of use, reapplying [slacy's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8439761/223092) from top related answer on the right gives you this solution:

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup

html = '''
<div>
<p>dvgbkfbnfd</p>
<div>
<span>dsvdfvd</span>
</div>
<p>fvjdfnvjundf</p>
</div>
'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
for match in soup.findAll('div'):
    match.replaceWithChildren()

print soup
```

... which produces the output:

```
<p>dvgbkfbnfd</p>

<span>dsvdfvd</span>

<p>fvjdfnvjundf</p>
```

Comment: Note: as per https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#method-names : from BS4 onward, it is best to use "unwrap" rather than "replaceWithChildren".