# Beautiful Soup Parsing Error

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to use beautifulsoup to first remove the `<a>` tags in the html string, but keep it's content. After that I would like to remove all tags and replace them with new lines.

The strip_tags function is from [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1765848/remove-a-tag-using-beautifulsoup-but-keep-its-contents).

Here is an example of what I am trying to do:

```
text = "<p>This is a <a>test</a></p>"
soup = strip_tags(text, ["a"])
plain_text = soup.get_text("\n")
print(plain_text)
```

For some reason the output is `u'This is a \ntest'`. If the `<a>` tag is stripped out already why does it think it is still there?

The expected output is `This is a test`.

A more complex example: 
`<p>First</p><a>Link</a><p>Second</p>`

How can I separate between `<p>` tags, and still be able to strip the `<a>` tag out?

Indeed if you print `soup.encode_contents()`, no `<a>` is there.

Comment: `u'This is a test'`. If there is no tag there should be no new line.

Comment: The breaks aren't because it sees an 'a' tag. It's because the NavigableString element of Soup contains multiple unicode strings and the get_text function prints the \n after every element in soup's NavigableString tree

Comment: The reason it is being added there is because `replacewith` when passed a simple string adds a  NavigableString

Comment: According to the crummy.com documentation: "A NavigableString is just like a Python Unicode string, except that it also supports some of the features described in Navigating the tree and Searching the tree." I think whats happening is you're removing the tags from the content but not fixing the tree's underlying elements. So when get_text() parses the tree it still sees extra "leafs" and puts in the "\n"s

Answer (score -1):

> The strip_tags function is from [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1765848/remove-a-tag-using-beautifulsoup-but-keep-its-contents).

That function replaces tags with text they contain, recursively.

Thus, your `'<a>test</a>'` is replaced with `'test'`. No `'<a>'` tags there.