# Beautiful Soup - strange characters returned when stripping HTML tags

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I have cribbed most of my code from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1765848/remove-a-tag-using-beautifulsoup-but-keep-its-contents?rq=1) accepted Stack Overflow answer and inserted into the following code (running in Python 2.7):

```
import SelectProxy
from  bs4 import BeautifulSoup, NavigableString
import requests
import json

sys.path.append("G:\\Python27\\Kodi")

session = requests.Session()

url = 'http://www.tvguide.co.uk/mobile/channellisting.asp?ch=66'


headers = {
'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8',
'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate',
'Accept-Language': 'en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.',
'Connection': 'keep-alive',
'Host': 'www.tvguide.co.uk',
'Referer': 'http://www.tvguide.co.uk/mobile/',
'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests': '1',
'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/65.0.3325.181 Safari/537.36'
}

r = session.get(url, headers=headers)

print r.text



def strip_tags(html, invalid_tags):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")

    for tag in soup.findAll(True):
        if tag.name in invalid_tags:
            s = ""

            for c in tag.contents:
                if not isinstance(c, NavigableString):
                    c = strip_tags(unicode(c), invalid_tags)
                s += unicode(c)

            tag.replaceWith(s)

    return soup

invalid_tags = ['td', 'tr', 'div', 'a', 'span', 'br']
print strip_tags(html, invalid_tags)
```

...this removes the tags alright, but I am now getting lots of strange text printed to screen as so:

```
&amp;amp;amp;lt;/body&amp;amp;amp;gt;&amp;amp;amp;lt;/html&amp;amp;amp;gt;
&amp;amp;amp;lt;html&amp;amp;amp;gt;&amp;amp;amp;lt;body&amp;amp;amp;gt;

                        The latest national and international stories as they break   

                            &amp;amp;amp;amp;lt;html&amp;amp;amp;amp;gt;&amp;amp;amp;amp;lt;body&amp;amp;amp;amp;gt;
&amp;amp;amp;amp;lt;/body&amp;amp;amp;amp;gt;&amp;amp;amp;amp;lt;/html&amp;amp;amp;amp;gt;
&amp;amp;amp;amp;lt;html&amp;amp;amp;amp;gt;&amp;amp;amp;amp;lt;body&amp;amp;amp;amp;gt;&amp;amp;amp;amp;lt;/body&amp;amp;amp;amp;gt;&amp;amp;amp;amp;lt;/html&amp;amp;amp;amp;gt;
&amp;amp;amp;amp;lt;html&amp;amp;amp;amp;gt;&amp;amp;amp;amp;lt;body&amp;amp;amp;amp;gt;Rating:  &amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;lt;html&amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;gt;&amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;lt;body&amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;gt;3.1&amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;lt;/body&amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;gt;&amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;lt;/html&amp;amp;amp;amp;amp;gt;&amp;amp;amp;amp;lt;/body&amp;amp;amp;amp;gt;&amp;amp;amp;amp;lt;/html&amp;amp;amp;amp;gt;
&amp;amp;amp;lt;/body&amp;amp;amp;gt;&amp;amp;amp;lt;/html&amp;amp;amp;gt;
&amp;amp;lt;/body&amp;amp;gt;&amp;amp;lt;/html&amp;amp;gt;
&amp;lt;/body&amp;gt;&amp;lt;/html&amp;gt;
```

...can anyone please advise what I am doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Rather than trying to throw everything away and be left with text, you should be using it to extract the required text. Your question does not explain what you are trying to get. Normally for such websites, you find all TR/TD tags and extract the text inside.

Comment: all i am after is the text though. this is a webscraper.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tags are there to help you get to the text you want. Most of the text in that page is inside HTML tables which can be extracted as follows:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import re

r = requests.get('http://www.tvguide.co.uk/mobile/channellisting.asp?ch=66')
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "html.parser")

for tr in soup.select('table tr'):
    if not tr.script:
        print ' -'.join(re.sub(r'\s+', ' ', td.text) for td in tr.find_all('td'))
```

This would give you output starting:

```
6:00am - Breakfast A round-up of national and international news, plus sports reports, weather forecasts and arts and entertainment features. Including NewsWatch at 7.45 Rating: 1.4 
7:00am - Breakfast A round-up of national and international news, plus sports reports, weather forecasts and arts and entertainment features. Including NewsWatch at 7.45 Rating: 1.4 
8:00am - Breakfast A round-up of national and international news, plus sports reports, weather forecasts and arts and entertainment features. Including NewsWatch at 7.45 Rating: 1.4 
9:00am - BBC News The latest national and international stories as they break Rating: 3.1 
10:00am - BBC News The latest national and international stories as they break Rating: 3.1 
10:30am - The Travel Show 20/04/2018 Join the team on their journey of discovery as they explore new destinations around the globe and uncover hidden sides to some of the world's favourite holiday hotspots Rating: 4 
11:00am - BBC News The latest national and international stories as they break Rating: 3.1 
11:30am - Dateline London 21/04/2018 Foreign correspondents currently posted to London look at events in the UK through outsiders' eyes, and at how the issues of the week are being tackled around the world Rating: 6.3 
12:00pm - BBC News The latest national and international stories as they break Rating: 3.1 
12:30pm - Click 20/04/2018 A guide to the latest gadgets, websites, games and computer industry news Rating: 3.3
```

Comment: Could simplify your loop by using `for tr in soup.select('table tr')`...

Comment: thanks all. still getting my eye in with beautiful soup.