# Why is my HTML sanitizer not removing tags?

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, html-sanitizing

I have written the following simple HTML filter using `requests` and `BeautifulSoup` that is supposed to take a list of allowed tags and attributes, and removes any tags that are not in the list:

```
def filter_tags(soup, tags_to_keep, allowed_attrs=None):

    for tag in soup.body.descendants:
        if tag.name in tags_to_keep:
            new_attrs = dict()
            for k,v in tag.attrs.items():
                if allowed_attrs and k in allowed_attrs:
                    new_attrs[k] = v
            tag.attrs = new_attrs

        elif isinstance(tag, NavigableString):
            continue

        else:
            # insert one whitespace char so words on either side of tag aren't concat'ed together
            tag.insert_before(" ")
            tag.decompose()

    return soup
```

I am calling the function like this: `soup = filter_tags(soup, tags_to_keep=['html', 'body', 'div', 'a'], allowed_attrs=['href'])`.

This function seems to work for simple inputs like this:

```
<body>
    <div id="cats">
        This is a test
        <a href="http://www.google.com">Google!</a> 
        More text
    </div>
    <div>
        More text
        <script>...oh javascript...</script>
    </div>
</body>
```

By "works" I mean that it correctly removes the `<script>` and `<img>` tags, and the `id=` attribute, while keeping specified tags and `href=` attr), so it looks like this afterwards:

```
<body>
    <div>
        This is a test
        <a href="http://www.google.com">Google!</a> 
        More text
    </div>
    <div>
        More text
    </div>
</body>
```

However for more complex HTML it fails entirely (an example of a page that fails is `http://www.cnn.com`), and `<script>` tags, tag attributes, etc are not being stripped from the HTML. I am getting output like this:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get('http://www.cnn.com').text, 'lxml')
filter_tags(soup, tags_to_keep=['body', 'a', 'div'], allowed_attrs=['href'])

              |
              |
              V    

... <li class="m-legal__list__item last-child">
<a class="m-legal__links" data-analytics="footer_cnn-newsource" href="http://cnnnewsource.com">CNN Newsource</a></li>
</ul></div></div></div></div></div></footer>
<div class="OUTBRAIN" data-ob-template="cnn" data-src="" data-widget-id="TR_1"></div>
 <script>(function (d) ...
```

As you can see, it is not removing any of the tags/attrs such as `<script>` or `class=` in more complex HTML like this,  but I can't figure out why based on my simple tests, where it seems to work fine...

What is wrong with my function above that is making it fail to remove tags/attributes for complex HTML? My intuition is that it might have something to do with modifying the DOM tree with `.decompose()` as I am traversing `.descendants`, but I can't tell for sure. If this is the problem, what is an alternative to the method I'm attempting to use here?

Comment: what library are you using to get the HTML content of CNN? requests?

Comment: Yes, I am using `requests` and `BeautifulSoup`. Sorry, I will clarify that in main post. However, I have manually inspected the HTML from `www.cnn.com` and requests is correctly downloading it. The `filter_html()` function is simply not removing other tags like `<script>` from it, while it does remove it for the simple example above.

Comment: yeah just tested it out of my computer and I'm getting the same issue. Hope someone will be able to help.

Comment: It seems `.descendants` doesn't return chilren tags deeper than one level, try `.find_all()`.

Comment: t.m. adam - From the bs4 docs for [.descendants](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#descendants): "*The .descendants attribute lets you iterate over all of a tag’s children, recursively: its direct children, the children of its direct children, and so on*".

Comment: ... yes, looking at the [source code for bs4.Tag](https://bazaar.launchpad.net/~leonardr/beautifulsoup/bs4/view/head:/bs4/element.py), `.descendants` definitely does appear to recurse to bottom level. So I don't think the issue is `descendants` not going past one level. But as far as using `find_all()` how were you suggesting doing that, given that I am trying to *filter out* all but given set of tags and insert whitespace in their place? I can see that going the other way (*selecting* given tags, etc), but can't understand how I'd use `find_all()` to do what I am trying to do.

Comment: The problem is with calling decompose() on elements you are iterating through. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1765848/remove-a-tag-using-beautifulsoup-but-keep-its-contents for a way to do it properly.